# Firebase Swift 3.0 setValuesForKeysWithDictionary

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Here is the code:

```
func observeMessages() {

    let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("messages")
    ref.observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

        if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
            let message = Message()
            message.setValuesForKeys(dictionary)
            self.messages.append(message)
            //this will crash because of background thread, so lets call this on dispatch_async main thread
            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            })
        } 
        }, withCancel: nil)

}
```

When run, it crashes like this:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key name.'

Please kindly help me fix this.

Comment: create a variable name in Message. it will fix the issue

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that there is a mismatch between your `Message` model class and what you are trying to put inside of your instance of it through the `setValuesForKeys` method. Your dictionary does not line up with the `Message` class.

This is what the error message tells you: your app tried to set a value for a key from your `snapshot.value` that does not exist in your `Message` class.

Check that there is exactly the **same number of properties with the same name** in your `Message` class as in your `snapshot.value`.

To avoid mismatches, you could define your `Message` class as such:

```
class Message: NSObject {

    var fromId: String?
    var text: String?
    var timestamp: NSNumber?
    var toId: String?
    var imageUrl: String?
    var imageWidth: NSNumber?
    var imageHeight: NSNumber?

    init(dictionary: [String: AnyObject]) {

        super.init()
        fromId = dictionary["fromId"] as? String
        text = dictionary["text"] as? String
        timestamp = dictionary["timestamp"] as? NSNumber
        toId = dictionary["toId"] as? String
        imageUrl = dictionary["imageUrl"] as? String
        imageWidth = dictionary["imageWidth"] as? NSNumber
        imageHeight = dictionary["imageHeight"] as? NSNumber
    }

}
```